# Python: How do you make a title screen on pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, page-title

How would you put in a title screen/ending screen in pygame? Using the Enter key to continue and the Esc key to quit.

I have a title screen that I personally made off of photoshop and I'd like to just insert it into the beginning of the game and just have the user either press Enter or Esc. How would I do that?

Comment: A very, very basic implementation of your question would be a simple event loop, which draws your title/ending screen picture, and checks the [pygame event queue](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) for the enter key or esc key presses to change the game state, or `pygame.quit()`.  You need to provide more information in order to get a real answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are many Pygame resources out there on the web. A recent book released by Al Sweigart, [Making Games with Python and Pygame](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/index.html) has some examples of what you are describing.

In particular, take a look at the following sample [program](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter6.html). This has some functions that will accomplish what you want to do, namely the showStartScreen(), checkForKeyPress(), and drawPressKeyMsg() functions.